# C++11 numeric_limits<>::max() at compile time

Tags: visual-c++, c++11

When I was trying to get something to compile on MSVC, I found out (sigh) that the version used in Visual Studio Express 2013 doesn't support `constexpr` functions yet. Therefore, I couldn't pass the result of `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` to a template. I can hack around this by just casting -1 to `size_t`, but I don't think this would strictly be portable, as (correct me if I'm wrong) the two's complement way of defining negatives isn't standardized (yet).

What is the recommended approach on doing this?

Comment: The internal representation - two's complement or otherwise - has nothing to do with it. The standard requires unsigned arithmetic to be performed modulo `2^n` (where `n` is the number of significant bits). So casting `-1` to an unsigned type produces the value `2^n-1`.

Comment: Unsigned integers have completely specified semantics, so that isn't a hack,

Comment: There's also `SIZE_MAX` in `cstdint`.

Comment: Ah right... of course. Silly me, thanks! :-)

Comment: There is a compiler update for `VS 2013` that supports `constexpr`. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx Note that it is a  Customer Technology Preview so better not use it in production code.

Answer (score 4):

The [boost integer library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/traits.html) is ported to many platforms and has a max constant: `boost::integer_traits<size_t>::const_max`.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class T, class Enable = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>>
struct NumericLimits {
  static const T sk_min_ = 0;
  static const T sk_max_ = static_cast<T>(-1);
};
```

usage as a template parameter:

```
template <class T, T N>
class X{};

template <class T>
class Y {
  // to instantiate X here you need a templated way
  // to get the max value of `T` because you don't know
  // what `T` actually is so you can't use something like INT_MAX
  X<T, NumericLimits<T>::sk_max_> x_;
};

auto y = Y<unsigned long>{};
```

An unsigned variable is guaranteed by the standard to wrap around. So if you want to use a general way to get the max value of an unsigned type (including as a template argument) the above code will work.

For signed types I don't know if there is a conforming way other than specializing for each type (there are only a few (`char`, `signed char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` so that is duable too). (and I mean use `INT_MAX`, not hard coded values as you don't know the range of the implementation)

Please note that I've test it on `g++` with `c++14` so it might need little tweaks to work on Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought of rolling my own too, but was under the impression that reinterpretation `-1` was subject to the two's complement way of defining negative integers. Apparently it's not, so this is fine to use :-) I don't really need a generalized version though, so I'll just use a `static_cast`. It's a real pain getting modern C++ to compile on MSVC... I'm way too used to GCC and Clang.